# Is simultaneuos reading and then writing of NFC tag possible in android?

Tags: android, nfc

I have a Mifare Desfire EV1 Card which I am using as a Type 4A Tag. I want to read and then write to the Tag immediately without re-tapping after reading it. Is this possible to write an application in android to do such thing...Please help

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Basically (NDEF) read is done by default by the Android subsystem, you can then select to write.

I've put up some templates [here](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) is you are interested, although you'd have to combine two of them to have the desired effect.